# Accessing to a variable named variablename+number

Tags: java, variables

I have always wondered:

- If I a have for example 8 JLabels named label1, label2, label3...
- I receive a message to show in one of them and an integer number from 1 to 8

Is there any smart way to access the variable named label+number without using a switch or a bunch of if-elses? And if so, is it more efficient than the switch/if-elses method?

I'm labeling for Java, but I think it is an interesting question for any classic language.

Comment: Why don't you use an array `JLabel[] label`? Then you could access them using `label[x-1]` (x being 1 to 8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) for it, but it will suffer from bad performance, or you can do it using a `Map<Integer,JLabel>`, which was precomputed with your objects.

For the more general case, reflection is probably what you are looking for.

Simple example of the usage of reflection:

```
public class TestSomething {
    public int elem1 = 1;
    public int elem2 = 2;
    public int elem3 = 3;
    public int elem4 = 4;
    public static void main(String[] str) throws NoSuchFieldException,IllegalAccessException {
        TestSomething test = new TestSomething();
        int num = 3;
        Field field = test.getClass().getField("elem" + num);
        System.out.println(field.get(test));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer :) Anyway, how many checks (aproximately) should a switch statement have to have a worse performance than reflection? Isn't a Map also worse from a switch (just not as worse as reflection)?

Comment: @RomanRdgz: it is hard to estimate how many switches will be needed to get worst performance then reflection, since one of the draw backs of reflection is jvm optimizations, which are not made when you use reflection. for `Map` solution: note that if you use a `HashMap`, search time is `O(1)`, which is not true for switch statements. However, I think those micro optimizations are seldom a consideration to prefer one on the other, since the difference in performance is *usually* small. Readability should usually be the consideration to choose one over the others.

Comment: So, If I have understood, A HashMap should be faster than a switch statement?

Comment: @RomanRdgz: For *extremely* large number of switch statements, it will *probably* do.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the labels in an [array](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-arrays.html) (or a [collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Reflection: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

e.g.

```
int i = 0;
Field f = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("prefix" + i);
f.setInt(this, 42);
```

Reflection isn't particularly fast but it is very flexible. For your example you would *probably* get the best performance using a switch statement.